# Giving a specific ID to a job created by Kue

Tags: node.js, redis, kue

I'm working with Kue and I'm creating Jobs to be added to Redis.

The problem i have is that when i destroy and recreate the Redis DB the Ids of the job created starts from 1.

so is there any way to create a job with Kue with a specific id so in Redis it will not start by 1 but by the id that i will specify.

Answer (score 0):

The last job id is maintain by this key `ids` (see https://github.com/Automattic/kue/blob/87d61503d3d9cc024633efc7611bd25551f0f87d/lib/queue/job.js#L799)

In theory, you can set the id by setting the `ids` to a new number (says 1000) before you start your Kue process. Then the id will start from 1001 in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I couldn't test it in my code. I'm using NodeJS and didn't find the function getkeys in an instance of the REDIS client. So do you  know any direct méthode or example showing how to change the id  ??

Comment: thank you for your answer ! it works with redis-cli